# How to redirect user to a specific route when tries to refresh the page manually in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to re-direct the user to a specific route when the user tries to refresh the page. Also, is there any way to show an alert before routing to a different URL?

I have tried the approach given below but when I navigate back to the page the user gets navigated to that specific URL without refreshing the page.

```js
useEffect(() => {    
  // Check if flag exists   
  if (localStorage.getItem("redirectAfterRefresh")) {
    localStorage.removeItem("redirectAfterRefresh");
    // Redirect user to specific page
    window.location.href = "/ndr";  // Replace with your actual URL
  } else {
    // Set flag for next refresh
    localStorage.setItem("redirectAfterRefresh", true);
  }

  return () => {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Are you using the react router?

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom: 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```html
useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
    // Show an alert before navigating away
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
    const confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
    return confirmationMessage;
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

  // Check if flag exists
  if (localStorage.getItem('redirectAfterRefresh')) {
    localStorage.removeItem('redirectAfterRefresh');
    // Redirect user to specific page after showing the alert
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to navigate away?')) {
      window.location.href = '/test'; // Replace with your actual URL
    }
  } else {
    // Set flag for next refresh
    localStorage.setItem('redirectAfterRefresh', true);
  }

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
  };
}, []);
```